Understanding ordered fields and the subset $P \subseteq \mathbb{F}$ of positive elements.
I'm following Real Analysis: A Long-Form Textbook (Jay Cummings) and there is a part about defining the positive set $P \subseteq \mathbb{F}$.
The following definition is given:

An ordered field is a field $\mathbb{F}$, along with the following additional axiom:
Axiom: There is a nonempty subset $P \subseteq \mathbb{F}$, called the positive elements such that
(a) if $a,b \in P$, then $a+b \in P$ and $a \cdot b \in P$; and
(b) if $a \in \mathbb{F}$ and $a \neq 0$, then either $a \in P$ or $-a \in P$.

However, I find the $-a \in P$ a little odd. Clearly this can't mean that negative numbers are part of $P$. Since suppose that $-1$ and $-2$ are in $P$, then (a) could not hold since $(-1) \cdot (-2) = 2 \notin P$. So what does that part of the definition serve? Is it so that we can define -(-2)? Or is this more obvious in a case where we are not talking about numbers (I assume there must also be an ordered field of for example functions or so?)

Do you now how the absolute value $|a|$ of a real number is defined? For $a\ge 0$, $|a|=a$, and for $a<0$, $|a|=-a$. In the latter case, $-a$ is not negative! It's the negation of $a$ (which itself is negative $a<0$), so e.g. for $a=-3$, $-a$ is $-(-3)$, or just 3.

Without (b), $P$ may not define a total order on $\mathbb F$. For instance, consider $\mathbb F = \mathbb C$ and $P = $ the upper right quadrant, which still fulfils (a).

No, it does not mean that negative numbers belong to $P$. In the first place, you would have to define the meaning of negative number before saying that. In the second place, what it says there is that for every element $a$ of $\Bbb F$ (other than $0$), $a\in P$ or $-a\in P$. That's nothing new, is it? Take, say, the real number $3$. I suppose that you agree that $3\in(0,\infty)$ or that $-3\in(0,\infty)$ (actually, it is true that $3\in(0,\infty)$ and it is false that $-3\in(0,\infty)$). Or take the number $-\pi$. Again, I suppose that you agree that $-\pi\in(0,\infty)$ or that $\pi\in(0,\infty)$.
After having a subset $P$ of a field $\Bbb F$ with the properties that you mentioned, then we can define the positive numbers as the elements of $P$ and the negative numbers as those $a\in\Bbb F$ such that $-a\in P$. Or you can define the positive numbers as the elements of $P\cup\{0\}$ and the negative numbers as those $a\in\Bbb F$ such that $-a\in P\cup\{0\}$. It's a matter of taste.
